# IBM Cloud Private - Error loading charts

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I installed IBM Cloud Private CE 2.1.0.1 for some testing on a virtual Ubuntu Server environment. In dashboard i can't open Catalog / Helm Charts. After a few seconds of loading screen there is a error message "Error loading charts".

Is there any solution?

edit

Log of my helm-api pod:

```
2018-02-22T11:14:59.194Z 'FINE' 'repos/ GET entry'
2018-02-22T11:14:59.193Z 'FINE' 'inspect-client -> redirecting to `next`'
2018-02-22T11:14:59.195Z 'FINE' 'charts GET /'
2018-02-22T11:14:59.195Z 'FINE' 'getAllRepoUrlsFromDb'
2018-02-22T11:14:59.195Z 'FINE' 'inspect-client -> redirecting to `next`'
 [0mGET /helm-api/api/v1/repos  [32m200  [0m34.874 ms - 301 [0m
2018-02-22T11:15:03.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:15:03.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:15:03.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.415 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:15:13.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:15:13.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:15:13.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.449 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:15:17.258Z 'FINE' 'dbHealthcheck \nrepoName: ibm-charts\n'
2018-02-22T11:15:17.258Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
2018-02-22T11:15:17.265Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:15:17.265Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m7.318 ms - 16 [0m
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.439 ms - 16 [0m
   [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.424 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:16:17.258Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
2018-02-22T11:16:17.258Z 'FINE' 'dbHealthcheck \nrepoName: ibm-charts\n'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m6.147 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:16:17.264Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:16:17.264Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:16:23.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:16:23.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:16:23.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.419 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:16:33.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:16:33.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:16:33.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.455 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:16:43.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:16:43.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:16:43.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.373 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:16:47.258Z 'FINE' 'dbHealthcheck \nrepoName: ibm-charts\n'
2018-02-22T11:16:47.258Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
2018-02-22T11:16:47.265Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m8.673 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:16:47.265Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:16:53.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:16:53.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
2018-02-22T11:16:53.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.421 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:17:03.720Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
2018-02-22T11:17:03.720Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
2018-02-22T11:17:03.720Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
 [0mGET /healthcheck  [32m200  [0m0.435 ms - 16 [0m
2018-02-22T11:17:06.471Z 'ERROR' 'getChartsFromRepo(recursive) error:  connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.112.133:443'
2018-02-22T11:17:13.716Z 'FINE' 'GET /healthcheck'
2018-02-22T11:17:13.716Z 'FINE' 'loadMessages en'
2018-02-22T11:17:13.716Z 'FINE' 'getMessage ["statusCode",200] en '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the default 'ibm-charts' helm repository from ICP console, and then click 'Sync repositories' to sync-up the charts. The URL is:
ICP Main Menu -> Manage -> Helm Repositories

After above steps, the "Error loading charts" error will gone. And then you can refer ICP documentation to manage helm charts:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/app_center/app_center.html

Answer (score 0):

some similar discussions:

[ibm-cloud-private CE - 2.1.0 Catalog - Error Loading Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941797/ibm-cloud-private-ce-2-1-0-catalog-error-loading-charts)

sometimes leave it for a while and it should resolve. Or

```
[root@kvm-014170 ~]# kubectl -s 127.0.0.1:8888 -n kube-system get pods|grep helm                                                              *
helm-api-86494f54f4-4m2ss                                 1/1       Running    1                                                              31        57d
helmrepo-6ff49569b8-wfcbw                                 1/1       Running    1
```

try kill the helm-api or helmrepo pod and wait for it restart.

Please use the search function to avoid posting similar issues.

Comment: killing these pods doesn't work for me :/ any other ideas?

Comment: added the log-output of my helm-api pod while opening the catalog / Helm Charts Site